# Trouble Copying an Inputted String to a Dynamically Created Spot in Memory

Tags: c

My assignment has me copying the string inputted to a destination that I dynamically allocate. I get the length of the string, dynamically allocate space for the new string, and try to copy the whole string to the pointer "dst", but it only copies the first char of the inputted string and then gives me a segmentation fault. This happens no matter how much memory I allocate. I'm pretty sure I messed up with the pointers somewhere, probably in malloc(). My question is what do I change to have the whole inputted string copy to the destination.

main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20
#define DEBUG 0

int g(int argc, char **argv) 
{

  char* dest = NULL;

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: a7Tester <string> \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    strCopy(argv[1], &dest);

    if (!dest)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (strcmp(argv[1], dest))
        printf("strCopy FAILED \n");
    else
        printf("strCopy Successful \n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

strCopy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DEBUG 0

/* 
 * This function copies src string to *dst
 * memory for *dst should be allocated
*/
void strCopy(char* src, char** dst)
{
    // define required variables
    char word[5];
    // Find the length of source (src) string
    // Do not use any library call such as strlen()
    int length = 0;
    while (src[length]!='\0') {
        length++;
    }
    // allocate memory for destination (*dst) string

    *dst = (char*) malloc(length*sizeof(char));
    
    // if memory allocation fails print approriate error message using perror() 
    // and return   

    if (dst == NULL) {
        perror("Space Not Allocated Correctly");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // copy src to *dst. 
    // Do not use any library call such as strcpy()
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        *dst[i] = src[i];
        printf("%c\n", *dst[i]);
    }
    
#if DEBUG
    printf("str: %s \n", str);
    printf("str: %s \n", *dst);
#endif
    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow one more character when you allocate `dst` for the terminating null character:

```
*dst = (char*) malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Since `dst` is a pointer to a pointer, you need to dereference it when copying. You also need to set the terminating null byte in the destination:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    *dst[i] = src[i];
    printf("%c\n", *dst[i]);
}
*dst[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: Also `if (dst == NULL)` -> `if (*dst == NULL)`

Comment: True, @Jabberwocky